# dot net core upload zip file - empty file

Tags: .net, upload, zipf

I have a post to upload file and it is ok for pdf, txt, docx. When I try to upload zip file, I can't extract the files because the file is empty. Some ideas? Thanks in avance.
public retOp UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
try
{
string PathFile = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", Configuration.GetTempDir());
if (!Directory.Exists(PathFile))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(PathFile);
}
var formFile = file;
if (formFile.Length > 0)
{
string fullPath = Path.Combine(PathFile, file.FileName);
using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
{
formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
} .....

Answer (score 0):

**I Think you should get Formfile from HttpContext.Request**

```cs
public class UploadController: ControllerBase
{
    //this should be your uploadService
    private readonly IUploadService _uploadService;
    public UploadController(IUploadService uploadService)
    { _uploadService = uploadService; }

    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public IActionResult Upload()
    {
        //get file from Request
        var formFile = Request.Form.Files[0];
        _uploadService.UploadFile(formFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm testing with Swagger and I have some problem to send a file in UI Swagger using Request.Form

Answer (score 0):

The problem: the method was not async and I had a "stream.readtimeout".
This is the change:

```
public async Task<retOp> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file)
 {
  try    
    {
    ....
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, 
     FileMode.Create))
      {
       await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
     } ....
```

Best regards